# Is there an alternative to get the Golang code completion in VS Code without installing Go?

Tags: go

My goal is to use Go exclusively on Docker. In other words, I try my best not to install Go directly to my computer. And, I am writing the code on a VS Code and use the "Go" extension.

The problem is that when I create a `main.go` it throws an error:

```
Failed to find the "go" binary in either GOROOT() or PATH(/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin). Check PATH, or Install Go and reload the window. If PATH isn't what you expected, see https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/971
```

Is there an alternative to get the code completion feature in VS Code?

Comment: No. Code completion relies on the code it's completing, much of which is in the standard library, which is part of the Go install.

Comment: "My goal is to use Go exclusively on Docker." You might want to explain the rational behind this decision as it is rather unusual _for_ _Go_ (which makes a local development setup really easy in comparison to other languages).

Comment: I use Apple Silicon, and I am afraid that I will have a problem of "it works on my machine, why it does not work on my Intel server". I am afraid, I will compile it to target Apple Silicon instead of Intel.

Answer (score 1):

This should be achievable using the Remote Development Extension pack. VSCode has good documentation on using containers as your development enviroment. This will allow you to enjoy all of the Go extension's features without needing Go to be installed directly on your machine. You can opt to install the extensions in the container as well.

See [Developing inside a Container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

Comment: I use Apple Silicon, one of the reason why I don't want to install Go binary directly, to avoid "it works here, why it does not work in the server". Anyway, if I use WSL2, can I target the compiler with Intel chip?

Comment: Yes. You would have to set the GOARCH environment variable to amd64. See GOOS and GOARCH under "Optional environment variables" at https://go.dev/doc/install/source#environment